# How do I search with the "&" keyword, e.g I want food & drink

Tags: bootstrap-table

In bootstrap-table jquery (http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/)

How do I search with the "&" keyword, e.g I want **food & drink**.
However, when read the source code, it has .replace for `/&/` to `&amp;`. Any idea I can bypass this? It is impossible to ask user to key in `&amp;` in the search text box.

Comment: I have tried reading this about four times, so I know it is not just me. This question is not coherent.

Comment: initially I was posted this in the github issue, but community there asked me paste in stackoverflow iwth bootstrap-table tag. I had added more description to make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... im still a little unclear as there is no bug in core code.

See this fiddle which proves "&" search works fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/dabros/x8efv6wf/1/

---

If this somehow doesnt answer your needs, elaborate on exactly why.

Then look at some extensions like `multiple search`, `filter` and `filter-control`:

http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/extensions/

---

If still not happy, then create a custom search function. Easy to do if using server-side pagination, but possible even if client-side.

If you fixed on using `client-side` (not server side pagination + search, meaning that the js does the search, not your own server code) then look at custom search.

Relatively new feature i think, not used it myself as if i wanted a custom search i would use server-side code.

But here it is:

Custom search function #1956
https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/issues/1956

How to search within row details? #2007
https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/issues/2007

https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/pull/1979

That pull requests seems most detailed, it appears full example still otw, but shouldnt be hard if you read through there.

Though frankly, stick with plugins/extensions i listed above or use server-side code if still not happy - gives you far greater control with far simpler execution/code-maintenance.